# Call method in class from another method in same class which is running inside a instance function

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to call the method `clean` from `getUser`, but it returns `undefined`.
If I call `u.test()`, it works perfectly.

How can I solve this issue?

```
class User
    constructor: () ->
        @db = # connect to db...

    clean: (user, callback) ->
        delete user.password
        callback user


   getUser: (id) ->
       @db.get id, (err, user) ->
            @clean user, (u) -> console.log u

   test: () ->
           @clean {name: "test", password: "hello"}, (u) ->
                console.log u

u = new User
u.getUser()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `=>` for the inner function.

In your inner function, with ->, it's a normal function bound to `undefined` by default. With =>, you bind it to the `this` value of the function instantiation context.