# Call a function of a class, inside a function of the same class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript class:

```
class Teams
  rankings: ->
    this.nav_tabs_ajax_calls()

    window.history.pushState(
      '',
      '',
      CoffeeRoutes.path('rankings_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
    )

    $('li.active').removeClass('active')
    $('li:has(a[href="#rankings"])').addClass('active')

  exercises: ->
    this.nav_tabs_ajax_calls()

    window.history.pushState(
      '',
      '',
      CoffeeRoutes.path('exercises_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
    )

    $('li.active').removeClass('active')
    $('li:has(a[href="#exercises-list"])').addClass('active')

    $(document).on 'click', '#add-exercise', ->
      showModal("exercises", false, createModal);

    createModal("exercises");

  users: ->
    window.history.pushState(
      '',
      '',
      CoffeeRoutes.path('users_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
    )

    $('li.active').removeClass('active')
    $('li:has(a[href="#enrolled-students"])').addClass('active')

  graph: ->
    window.history.pushState(
      '',
      '',
      CoffeeRoutes.path('graph_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
    )

    $('li.active').removeClass('active')
    $('li:has(a[href="#graph"])').addClass('active')

    initialize_graph();

    $('#pause-resume').click ->
      if $('#pause-resume i').attr('class') == "fa fa-pause"
        pause()
        $('#pause-resume i').attr('class', 'fa fa-play')
        $('#pause-resume i').attr('title', 'Resume graph animation')

      else
        resume()
        $('#pause-resume i').attr('class', 'fa fa-pause')
        $('#pause-resume i').attr('title', "Stop graph animation")


     $('#back-center').click ->
       reset()

     $('#remove-graph').click ->
       dispose()

     $(document).on 'click', '#add-nodes', ->
       showModal('search', false, createModal)

     $(document).on 'click', '#search-btn', ->
       div = $(document.createElement('div'))
       div.attr('id', 'loading-modal')
       $('.modal-content').append(div)

  team_id: ->
    $('#show-team').data('team-id')

  nav_tabs_ajax_calls: ->
    $('a[href="#rankings"]').click ->
      $.ajax CoffeeRoutes.path('rankings_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'script'

    $('a[href="#exercises-list"]').click ->
      $.ajax CoffeeRoutes.path('exercises_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'script'

    $('a[href="#enrolled-students"]').click ->
      $.ajax CoffeeRoutes.path('users_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'script'

    $('a[href="#graph"]').click ->
      $.ajax CoffeeRoutes.path('graph_team', { 'id': this.team_id() })
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'script'
```

In `my nav_tabs_ajax_calls` function I'm receiving the following error (if I call my `rankings` function, for instance): `Uncaught TypeError: this.team_id is not a function(…)`.

Removing `this.nav_tabs_ajax_calls()` from my functions, it works fine, with no errors calling `this.team_id()` in my other functions.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "this" context will likely be the global Window since "this.team_id()" is actually being called from within the "click" event callback. You can either capture the team_id before attaching the "click" event listeners, or you can proxy the "click" callback functions.

```
nav_tabs_ajax_calls: ->
tID = this.team_id();
$('a[href="#rankings"]').click ->
  $.ajax CoffeeRoutes.path('rankings_team', { 'id': tID })
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'script'
// etc. replacing "this.team_id()" with "tID"
```

OR (and I'm not a coffeescript expert, so this may not be correct syntax)

```
$('a[href="#rankings"]').click ->
  $.proxy($.ajax(CoffeeRoutes.path('rankings_team', { 'id': tID }), {
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'script'
  }, this)
// etc.
```

Comment: But... I like @partho222's answer - seems more like coffeescript standard.

Comment: I knew that `=>` was the best solutions, but I took time to understand hot to use. It is, in fact, the best solution. Keeping what I did, just adding `=>` instead `->` in `click` event, solved my problem. Your examples helped to figure out what I was doing wrong, thanks a lot!

Comment: Have  a look at this answer to fully understand the => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184209/when-does-the-fat-arrow-bind-to-this-instance/13184211#13184211

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `=>` for inner functions.

Inner function, with `->` is a normal function bound to undefined by default. 
With =>, you bind it with the `this` value of the function instantiation context.

check this:
[Call method in class from another method in same class which is running inside a instance function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158917/call-method-in-class-from-another-method-in-same-class-which-is-running-inside-a)